# Python: replacing data in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

Hello i am attempting to adjust a CSV file using Python but my out put is a little off and I can't figure out why.

```
in_file = open(out, "rb")
fout = "DomainWatchlist.csv"
fin_out_file = open(fout, "wb")
csv_writer2 = csv.writer(fin_out_file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for item in in_file:
if "[.]" in item:
    csv_writer2.writerow([item.replace("[.]", ".")])
elif "[dot]" in item:
    csv_writer2.writerow([item.replace("[dot]", ".")])
else:
    csv_writer2.writerow([item])

in_file.close
fin_out_file.close
```

The input file contains data that looks like this:

```
bluecreatureoftheseas.com
12rafvwe[dot]co[dot]cc
12rafvwe[dot]co[dot]cc
404page[dot]co[dot]cc
abalamahala[dot]co[dot]cc
abtarataha[dot]co[dot]cc
adoraath[dot]cz[dot]cc
adoranaya[dot]cz[dot]cc
afnffnjq[dot]co[dot]cc
aftermorningstar[dot]co[dot]cc
```

I am attempting to fix this data but it comes out looking like this:

```
"12rafvwe.co.cc
"
"12rafvwe.co.cc
"
"404page.co.cc
"
"abalamahala.co.cc
"
"abtarataha.co.cc
"
"adoraath.cz.cc
"
"adoranaya.cz.cc
"
"afnffnjq.co.cc
"
"aftermorningstar.co.cc
"
"aftrafsudalitf.co.cc
"
"agamafym.cz.cc
"
"agamakus.vv.cc
```

Why does this create the extra quotes and then add a carriage return?

Comment: For future reference, you need to put a blank line before and after any code block for it to work. I fixed it for you here.

Comment: As a side note: There is absolutely no reason to use `csv` here. You've got a single-column file. Why not just `fout.write()` each line? (Alternatively, if you want to use `csv` to leave yourself room for future expansion to multiple columns, you probably want it on the input file as well.)

Answer (score 3):

The reason you're getting a newline is that `for item in in_file:` iterates over each line in `in_file`, without stripping the newline. You don't strip the newline anywhere. So it's still there in the single string in the list you pass to `writerow`.

The reason you're getting quotes is that in CSV, strings with special characters—like newlines—have to be either escaped or quoted. There are different "dialect options" you can set to control that, but by default, it tries to use quoting instead of escaping.

So, the solution is something like this:

```
for item in in_file:
    item = item.rstrip()
    # rest of your code
```

---

There are some other problems with your code, as well as some ways you're making things more complicated than they need to be.

First, `in_file.close` does not close the file. You're not calling the function, just referring to it as a function object. You need parentheses to call a function in Python.

But an even simpler way to handle closing files is to use a `with` statement.

You only have a single column, so there is no need to use the `csv` module at all. Just `fin_out_file.write` would work just fine.

You also probably don't want to use binary mode here. If you have a good reason for doing so, that's fine, but if you don't know why you're using it, don't use it.

You don't need to check whether a substring exists before `replace`-ing it. If you call `'abc'.replace('n', 'N')`, it will just harmlessly return `'abc'`. All you're doing is writing twice as much code, and making Python search each string twice in a row.

Putting this all together, here's the whole thing in three lines:

```
with open(out) as in_file, open(fout, 'w') as out_file:
    for line in in_file:
        out_file.write(line.replace("[.]", ".").replace("[dot]", "."))
```

Answer (score 0):

a bit OT but perl was built for this

```
$ perl -i -ple 's/\[dot\]/./g' filename
```

will do the job, including saving the new file on the oldfilename.

Comment: Why use perl when sed is even easier here (and lighter-weight)? Especially when you're adding flags to make perl act more sed-like?

Comment: yeah i guess you're right, i've just never bothered memorizing sed syntax because perl solves sed, but not the other way around.